# issues with entering variables into dictionary

Tags: variables, if-statement, python-3.4

here's my code, or rather the part of the code i'm having issues with.

the problem is at the `if` expression, where i'm trying to check whether a value is already in a dictionary (the actual code is in a larger `while` loop, used for a user interface), but when it runs the second time round it will always go into the else section, i'm assuming because of the variable name already being present in the dictionary.

```
    Dict1 = {#empty dictionary}
    completedList = (#list variable containing “true” and “false”)
    name = input(“enter your name”)
    score = completedList.count("true")
    callback = 'cont'
    while callback == 'cont':
        if name not in dict1 == True:
            dict1 = [name] = score
            callback = ""
        else:
            print("that name is already in use \n please choose another")
            name = input("enter a name")
```

I'm a student, so the simpler the code the better.

Answer (score 0):

```
    dict1 = {'er'}
    completedLis=()
    name = input("enter your name")
    score = completedLis.count("true")
    callback = 'cont'
    while (callback == 'cont'):
        if (name not in dict1):
            dict1 = name = score
            callback = ''
        else:
            print("that name is already in use \n please choose another")
            name = input("enter a name")
```

I hope this solves ur problem if u type er(dict1='er')it will go to else or if u type anything else it will work

Comment: i tried your answer, but, when i entered a name other than 'er',  it threw a - Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/waj2000/Desktop/er.py", line 7, in <module>
    if (name not in dict1):
TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable
-error at me, though the name i entered wasn't a integer as it's complaining.